# Will Vue.js follow up Angular 2.0?

Tags: vue.js

I love Angular 1.x and Vue.js. However, Angular 2.0 is coming soon. Will Vue.js upgrade structure as Angular 2.0? Does anyone know the plan from Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that... Vue version 1 just came out... And it does not intend to become a full blown framework (at least on its own). Maybe in the future.. but definitely not any time soon...

Love Vue and excited about Angular!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, angular 2 will be adjusting the way it watches variables to be more similar to how Vue does it.  See here http://vuejs.org/guide/comparison.html#Angular where Evan mentioned the differences between the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Both Vue.js 2 & ng 2 already came out. From what I saw, they have huge differences.I tried them both, And I prefer Vue.js 2, because its more easy to learn ...